# Problem including user-defined colormap in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a small problem with TikZ I can't figure out. I have some TikZ code generated in MATLAB (using matlab2tikz) showing an image with a user-defined colormap and the correspondent colorbar. The image is exported as .png but given that the colorbar is created in TikZ I need to color it accordingly (defining the new colormap). I simplified the code to get a MWE and it reads as follows (I replaced the user-defined colormap with a simple one):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{tikz}                       %inline graphics
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,external}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,height=4cm,axis on top,scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=5,xlabel={myxlabel},ymin=0,ymax=4000,
colorbar,
colormap ={mymap}{rgb(0pt)=(0,1,1); rgb(63pt)=(1,0,1)},
ylabel={myylabel}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

This works fine, but given that my colormap has more than two colors definitions, I thought that saving it in a separate .tex file, say mycmap.tex, was a nice idea

```
colormap ={mymap}{\input{mycmap}},
```

However, if I do this it doesn't work... I tried to save it as a .txt file instead of .tex, but still no luck. Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but choosing colormaps with less than 64 colors worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You may define a macro in your external file as in the below code (`filecontents` package and environment used to create the external file):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{tikz}                       %inline graphics
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,external}

%% creation of external colormap
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-external-colormap}
\def\mycolormap{rgb(0pt)=(0,1,1); rgb(63pt)=(1,0,1)}
\end{filecontents*}
%%

\input{\jobname-external-colormap}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,height=4cm,axis on top,scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=5,xlabel={myxlabel},ymin=0,ymax=4000,
colorbar,
colormap ={mymap}{\mycolormap},
ylabel={myylabel}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. I'm not really sure your solution solves my problem (which I had essentially forgotten :D), because my idea was including the colormap data from an external file.
However, I've also discovered why I was getting problem when using more than 2 color points; the syntax I was using:

`colormap={mymap}{rgb(0pt)=(0,1,1);rgb(30pt)=(1,1,1); rgb(63pt)=(1,0,1)}`
doesn't work because I don't indicate the parameter `[1pt]` at the beginning of the color declaration.

Comment: It should instead be:

`colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0,1,1);rgb(30pt)=(1,1,1); rgb(63pt)=(1,0,1)}`

and like this it works even with more colours.

Comment: @gbernardi My example uses an external file (here, this external file is created by `filecontents*` environment to keep my code auto-sufficient).